# Deserialize a list of objects without overarching object

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, serialization

Via an API Method I recieved a Json with the following format:

```
{" results ": [
    {
    " id ": " <entity token> ",
    " name ": " name ",
    " description ": " Datasource description ",
    " createTime ": 1190961927000 ,
    " modifyTime ": 1190962443000
    }
    {... (structure from above is repeated about 50 times)
    }
]}
```

I wrote a poco Class

```
Public Class Results_DSMeta
    Public Property results As List(Of DatasourceInfo)
End Class

Public Class DatasourceInfo
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property created As ULong
    Public Property modified As ULong
End Class
```

And deserialized the `Json` with

```
Dim datasourceInfo As Results_DSMeta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Results_DSMeta)(jstr)
```

Everything worked fine until yesterday since the provider changed the Json Format slightly to

```
[
    {
    " id ": " <entity token> ",
    " name ": " Datasource name ",
    " description ": " Datasource description ",
    " createTime ": 1190961927000 ,
    " modifyTime ": 1190962443000
    }
    {... (structure from above is repeated about 50 times)
    }
]
```

I just cannot figure out how to change my code to get this working since the `results` object is missing and I cannot create a overarching class like `Results_MSData` since I do not have an overarching Object in json (results) anymore. I started to only work with the DatasourceInfo Class and tried to loop this one but I guess there is a much easier solution. Another solution could be to just add `{" results ":[ ]` via string manipulation so I get the same Json as before, but this seems unprofessional to me as well. Can anyone help me out here? C# solution is welcome too.

Comment: You can deserialize that array of simple objects using `JToken.Parse`, `JArray.Parse`, or a `List(Of DatasourceInfo)`, provided that you fix the properties names, because, as of now, they don't match the json's (`created` = `createTime` etc.). If the properties names in the json do actually include spaces, you'll need a `JsonProperty` attribute, e.g., `[JsonProperty(" description ")] Public Property description As String`

Comment: In VB.Net the attribute is of couse written as `<JsonProperty(" description ")>` (I wrote the c# version :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basially, you don't need the `Results_DSMeta` Class anymore, only the `DatasourceInfo` Class. The data sent by the provider is still a list so, instead of defining that list as:

```vb
Dim datasourceInfo As Results_DSMeta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Results_DSMeta)(jstr)
```

You can use:

```vb
Dim datasourceInfo As List(Of DatasourceInfo) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of DatasourceInfo))(jstr)
```